# import error (all three import error)(when using breathboard)

Tags: python

```
import board
import busio
import adafruit_bmp280
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
sensor = adafruit_bmp280.Adafruit_BMP280_I2C(i2c)

print('Temperature: {} degrees C'.format(sensor.temperature)) 
print('Pressure: {}hPa'.format(sensor.pressure))
```

[this is the error shown while running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtMHR.jpg)

Comment: where is the board module defined? if it is in the same package you should use `from . import board`

Comment: still the error is shown in the first line

Comment: Put another way ... which library are you trying to use here?

Comment: adafruit library

Comment: we are using bmp280 sensor